# Animate buttons on scrolling

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

My animate button on scroll works exactly how it should, but now my mouseenter event seems to take a perlious amount of time to do what I want it to do. What it should do is when you scroll the Top button will show, and when you hover over the button the button will roll out, the yellow pro support button works correctly just not the blue one.

HTML

```
<a href="mailto:support@feeneywireless.com">
   <img class="prosupport" src="http://feeneywireless.com/assets/img/pro-support-btn.png">
</a>
<a id="head" href="#top">
   <img border="0" src="http://feeneywireless.com/assets/img/page/fixed-nav-top.png" class="top-button">
 </a>
```

Jquery

```
$(function () {
    $('.prosupport').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            right: "+=5.3em"
        }, 500).animate({
            right: "-.3em"
        }, 100);
    });
    $('.prosupport').mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            right: "-5.1em"
        }, 500);
    });
    $('.top-button').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            right: "+=2.5em"
        }, 500).animate({
            right: "-5.2em"
        }, 100);
    });
    $('.top-button').mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            right: "-7.3em"
        }, 500);
    });
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
        var scroll_pos_test = 50;
        if (y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) {
            $('.top-button').animate({
                right: "-7.5em"
            });
        }
    });
 });
```

---

JSFIDDLE
http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/NwG2j/6/

Comment: which one is yellow and which one is blue? can you provide a fiddle that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SE4Qv/

Comment: You could also try doing this with CSS, which makes your code a lot neater and more robust. Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/q9TWn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you were queueing the `$('.top-button').animate({right: "-7.5em"});` animation multiple times, as it triggers multiple times during a typical scroll action. That causes any other animations to be delayed. You need to ensure that animation is only done once. I did it by having the button's `display` set to `none` initially.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
        var scroll_pos_test = 50;     
        if(y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test && $('.top-button').css('display') == 'none') {
            $('.top-button').show().animate({right : "-7.5em"});
        }
    });
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NwG2j/10/)

Comment: Works perfect, thanks for the headsup for future development.